# C# Crafting Logic

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

There are many similar questions to this but none with a definitive answer. I am using Unity3D engine to create a game. I have set up a inventory system with methods to add items, remove items and check if the inventory contains a certain amount of an item.

What I want to do is on every update, loop through the items and if the player has the required items for the crafting recipe, show add a button the a list which the player can click on to craft the new item.

I thought I could use a Dictionary to store the items and quantities needed. Something like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> sword = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
        {"stone", 2},
        {"Wood", 1}
    };

    public static Dictionary<string, int> plank = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
        {"Wood", 5}
    };
```

But I also need a way to store all of the recipes and loop through them. Like a Dictionary of Dictionaries. So I could loop through all of the crafting item names. Can I do something similar to this?

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary> recipes = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    {"Wood Sword", sword},
    {"Wood Plank", plank}
};
```

I want to be able to define all the recipes in one class file and loop through them all in another.

I don't have to much experience with c# so I am not very good at using lists and dictionaries so I would appreciate any suggestions and help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Coming from your specs I came up with something like this:

```
    public enum Ingredient = { Wood, Stone, Water, Gold/*and so on*/ };

    public class RecipeItem 
    {
            public Ingredient Ingredient{ get; set;}
            public int Amount {get; set;}
    }

    public class Recipe
    {
            public string Name {get; set;}
            public List<RecipeItem> RecipeItems {get;set;}
    }
```

Somewhere in your code when defining recipes:

```
    var recipes = new List<Recipe>(){
            new Recipe(){
                    Name = "Wood Sword",
                    RecipeItems = new List<RecipeItem>(){
                            new RecipeItem(){
                                    Ingredient = Wood,
                                    Amount = 1
                            },
                            new RecipeItem(){
                                    Ingredient = Stone,
                                    Amount = 5
                            }

                    }
            },
            new Recipe(){
                    Name = "Plank",
                    RecipeItems = new List<RecipeItem>(){
                            new RecipeItem(){
                                    Ingredient = Wood,
                                    Amount = 5
                            }

                    }
            }
            // More recipes
    };
```

PS: I would recommend you spend few days on learning basics of C#

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>` - a `Dictionary` with a `string` key and `Dictionary<string, int>` values.  Initialize it like this:

```
var recipes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
{
    { "Sword", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "stone", 2 }, { "wood", 1 } } },
    { "Plank", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "wood", 5 } } }
};
```

Personally I find that a bit heavy and easy to mess with.  I'd be more inclined to use a structure to hold the internals, something like:

```
public struct RecipeComponent
{
    public readonly string Material;
    public readonly int Count;

    public RecipeComponent(string material, int count)
    {
        Material = material;
        Count = count;
    }   
}

public readonly Dictionary<string, RecipeComponent[]> recipes = new Dictionary<string, RecipeComponent[]>
{
    { "Sword", new[] { new RecipeComponent("stone", 2), new RecipeComponent("Wood", 1) } },
    { "Plank", new[] { new RecipeComponent("Wood", 5) } }
};
```

Slightly more robust, but you can still manipulate the contents of the `recipes` list at run-time, including replacing the list of required components.  A `ReadOnlyDictionary` helps solve that.

Answer (score 0):

By far(for me), the easiest way is with a generic list and for loops.
First: Use this function to check if the items are in the inventory
public bool CheckItems(List check) {

```
List<Item> it = new List<Item> (check);// Make sure original list is not changed.
        foreach(Item inventoryItem in myItems) {// Loop through your INVENTORY's items.
            if (it.Contains(inventoryItem)) {//If contains, remove.
                it.Remove(inventoryItem);
                if(it.Count == 0) {
                    return true; //When the count is less than zero, you can craft the item.
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This just needs to be called in the craft function, and if it returns true, you can craft the items.
Note: the Check list is the list of items the craft requires, and myItems is the list of items in inventory.